# JavaScript - weird bug doesn't remove element

Tags: javascript

I have a weird problem with my simple to-do app. Its main features are adding new elements to "ul" and clicking on "li" to change its class. After clicking element it also adds an "i" with font-awesome icon and after clicking it again it should remove it. It works fine when I click added elements from top to bottom, but when I click from bottom to top, "i" is removed only from the first element from top. I can't figure out why is that, so I would appreciate any help.

Here is live demo where you can reproduce this bug:
https://michalgrochowski.github.io/to-do/

And here is the code responsible for that action:

```
document.getElementById("list").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target && e.target.matches("li.item")) { 
    e.target.className = "itemDone"; 
    var check = document.createElement("i");
    check.className = "fa fa-check done"; 
    e.target.appendChild(check); 
  } else if (e.target && e.target.matches("li.itemDone")) {
    e.target.className = "item"; 
    var done = document.getElementsByClassName("done");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < done.length; i++) {
       e.target.removeChild(done[i]);
    };
  };
});
```

I've tested it in firefox and chrome, so it's not browser-related, it must be something in the code. I was thinking maybe the problem is with the loop inside the function, but I don't know how to change it.

Comment: the console says the error is on `e.target.removeChild(done[i]);` because: `Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.` check it using console.log to see with element is trying to call the removeChild method.

Comment: `e.target.getElementsByClassName("done");`

Comment: Couldn't reproduce on Chrome mobile. Looks functional to me.  I'm able to add and cross and delete in all orders top to bottom and reverse and random

Comment: And FYI, you don't need the `e.target &&` check. A `click` event will always have an `.target` on the event object.

Comment: Squint you are a genius, that line was the problem and changing it fixed it :) Post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as solved please.

Comment: @grhu: Go ahead and use the answer already posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var done = document.getElementsByClassName("done");` gets a list of all the `.done` elements in your document (including those who aren't child elements of `e.target`). So when executing `e.target.removeChild(done[i])` if the current `done[i]` is a child of `e.target`, it will be removed, otherwise it will throw an error saying that the element `done[i]` is not a child of `e.target`. Try this:

```
var done = e.target.getElementsByClassName("done");
```

**Note:** if there could be sub-elements (children of children ...) of `e.target` that have the class `.done`. This will throw an error too. Because then the sub-children won't be direct children of `e.target`. `removeChild` work only on direct children. You can avoid trouble by using this:

```
var done = e.target.children; // to get the direct children only
var i;
for (i = 0; i < done.length; i++) {
   if(done[i].matches('.done') // if it matches the criteria
       e.target.removeChild(done[i]); // remove it
}
```

Comment: Yes, that fixed the problem prefectly, like @squint wrote before in the comment :)